# APEX Request giving "errorCode" : "JSON_PARSER_ERROR" } ]

Tags: apex, rest

I have built a rest service and trying to create a record with a field of currency type.The rest service looks OK when parameter is been passed with some value However when the format of the request changes to **`"field__name":"null",`** It fails with :

```
[ {
  "message" : "N/A at [line:20, column:20]",
  "errorCode" : "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
} ]
```

I have used ternary operator to check the null value . However it is still failing (Request.field__name=='null')?0.0:Request.field__name;

Comment: You shouldn't quote wrap null. It's `null`, not `"null"`.

Comment: But if it is coming from third party, Cant we handle it through the code though ?

Comment: You can always just do string replacement...`payload = payload.replace('"null"', 'null');`